# How to reset all graphs and variables in keras/tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I want the names given to layers to be consistent as I imp.reload a module from the repl.

Currently names are being appended with numbers. like 'V' becomes 'V_2' et.

Comment: Please show a code sample of what you are trying to do, Thanks

Comment: keras.backend.reset_uids() basically does it thanks